# .NET Core: Play large video file that is stored in chunks of byte[] inside database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, video-streaming

I am building a .NET Core 3.1 application that is going to play large video files. Files are stored inside the database as small chunks of byte[] (I am planning to also encrypt each chunk) (10MB). Waiting for the whole stream to load all parts (and later decrypt them) and then play the whole video is not an option. I've tried searching online for some video streaming techniques but no luck since all of them are referring to the physical video file.

Is it possible to play video as soon as the first chunk arrives and then continue loading chunks in parallel with the playback?

This is my controller action (currently loading all the chunks in memory stream before returning it to the player):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Play(Guid guid)
{
    var videoFile = dbContext.VideoFiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Guid == guid);
    string contentType = GetContentType(videoFile.FileExtension);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    foreach (var chunk in dbContext.VideoFileChunks.Where(c => c.VideoFileId == videoFile.Id).OrderBy(x => x.ByteOffset))
    {
        await ms.WriteAsync(chunk.Content, 0, chunk.Content.Length);
    }
    return File(ms, contentType, enableRangeProcessing: true);
}

private string GetContentType(string fileExtension)
{
    switch (fileExtension.ToLower())
    {
        case ".mp4":
            return "video/mp4";
        case ".avi":
            return "video/x-msvideo";
        default:
            throw new Exception("File not supported");
     }
}
```

My models are

```
public class VideoFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OriginalFileName { get; set; }

    public string FileExtension { get; set; }

    public long TotalByteLength { get; set; }        

    public ICollection<VideoFileChunk> Chunks { get; set; } = new List<VideoFileChunk>();
}

public class VideoFileChunk
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int VideoFileId { get; set; }
    public long ByteOffset { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

    public VideoFile VideoFile { get; set; }

}
```

And the video player inside the view:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="@Url.Action("Play", new { guid = Model.Guid })" type="@(Model.ContentType)" />
    </video>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!! :)

Comment: I think this should not be possible, because you cannot determine when the video has finished playing the read segment, and reading the data and binding it again will cause the video to reload and refresh.

Comment: Did you find a solution?